# Using a js tooltip library with pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I want to use a simple tooltip on a PIXI.Graphics() object - a rectangle.

I tried tooltip.js (https://popper.js.org/tooltip-documentation.html) which won't work because my reference object is not a HTMLElement.

```
let rectangle = new PIXI.Graphics();
rectangle.drawRect(100, 50, 50, 20);
rectangle.interactive = true;
const tooltip = new Tooltip(rectangle, {title: "test1"});
rectangle.on('mouseover', (event) => {
tooltip.show();
});
rectangle.on('mouseout', (event) => {
tooltip.hide();
});
```

Is there any library i can make use of and still use my PIXI.Graphics() object? Or do I have to write my own tooltip that does not rely on a HTMLElement?

Answer (score 0):

popper.js v2 let's you reference a virtual element so your popup can end up anywhere you want: https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/virtual-elements/